# How do I see my count broken down by badge?

Tags: support, badges

For example, I just earned a second Revival badge.  But the badges page only displays a checkmark, which means that there's no obvious way to see the frequencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy. Click on your name, scroll to the bottom of the page, and you'll see the complete collection of badges you've earned. Here's that part of your profile from MSO:

[image]

Comment: You should post the screenshot from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/590042/foo-bah) instead, where really two revival badges are visible.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just interested in how many times you've received a particular badge, the information is [at the bottom of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590042/foo-bah#feed-link). For badges that can be earned multiple times, clicking the badge link on the profile page will show a page that lists which posts the badge was awarded for. For example, you can [view the posts you revived](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/837/revival?userid=590042).

Comment: Heh didn't realize that the x2 was right there at the bottom ...